# Shared memory safty, could you read and write at the same time and what would happen?

Tags: c++, memory, shared-memory

I am using the sys/shm library to share memory between two applications.
It works well and as I want it to, however I am unsure of the library is entirely safe in the way I currently have it implemented.

What would happen if a value is changed at the same time the other application tries to read it. Could this even happen in the first place? I dont know.

Here is a simplified version of my two applications:

Send:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int Delta_x{ atoi(argv[1]) }, Delta_y{ atoi(argv[2]) }, Delta_z{ atoi(argv[3]) };

    int shmid;
    int* array;
    int count = 3;
    int i = 0;
    int SizeMem;
    key_t key = ftok("shmfile", 66);

    SizeMem = sizeof(*array) * count;
    shmid = shmget(key, count * sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT);
    array = (int*)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);


    array[0] = Delta_x;
    array[1] = Delta_y;
    array[2] = Delta_z;

    shmdt((void*)array);
    return 0;
}
```

Recieve:

```
int* Recieve;
int x{ 0 }, y{ 0 }, z{0};

key_t key = ftok("shmfile", 66);
int shmid = shmget(key, 3 * sizeof(int), IPC_EXCL);
Recieve = (int*)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, SHM_RDONLY);

while (Condition)
{
    x = Recieve[0];
    y = Recieve[1];
    z = Recieve[2];
    std::cout << "x:" << x << ", y:" << y << ", z:" << z << std::endl;
    usleep(50000);
}

shmdt((void*)Recieve);
```

Is this implementation safe?

Comment: No, it's not safe. Concurrent access to shared memory segments is unspecified behavior. You will have to do some research on your own, to investigate whether it would be possible, on your implementation, to construct a mutex in shared memory (using placement new), and use it to synchronize access to the rest of the shared memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not safe.
I mean if you put your write code in a loop and the run the send code,the read code may be executed after the first write and before the last write.
It according the thread scheduler.

But your data in share memory are integer values. It can be write and read in one instruction,so the value your read from memory is always a value you wrote in.

And  reading/writing a valid integer would never make a program crash.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is exactly the same as in multithreading. To safely read/write data a safety mechanism like mutex is required.

Boost.Interprocess library has both various mutexes, semaphores, and  condition variables. Just don't expect them to be efficient as most OSs support for interprocessing has always been very limited.